# How to access IR camera (windows hello) video stream (windows)

Tags: windows, video, infrared

I have a camera which has a "normal" RGB sensor and an IR sensor (for windows hello).
I can open and access the RGB stream (and show it in my app), but how do I access the IR stream?

I am working in C/C++/Win32 but even something in C#/.NET would be useful.

Thanks,
Cyrille